# About semicolon in ES6 when using return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm new to JS. If I add a semicolon like this `${this.name} is friends with ${el}`; I'll get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". May I know why? Since in ES5, I can use semicolon like return this.name + ' is friends with ' +el;
Thank you so much!

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

ES6
Person.prototype.myFriends5 = function(friends) {
var arr = friends.map((el) =>
     `${this.name} is friends with ${el}`
);
console.log(arr);
}
var friends = ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Mark'];
new Person('John').myFriends5(friends);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions can be written in two ways:

```
(params) => expression
```

or

```
(params) => {
    body
}
```

where `body` is just like the body of a traditional function (a sequence of statements).

When you use the first format, you can't have a `;` because that's not valid in an expression, it's used to terminate statements in a function body. It's the same reason you can't write:

```
console.log(a;)
```

The first form is shorthand for:

```
(params) => {
    return expression;
}
```

A rule of thumb for what is a valid expression is that it's the same thing that can go inside parentheses. So if you can write something like:

```
a = (something)
```

then you can write:

```
(params) => something
```

Since you can't write:

```
a = (`${this.name} is friends with ${el}`;)
```

you can't write:

```
(params) => `${this.name} is friends with ${el}`;
```

Comment: Ah and may I know that in (params) => expression, does this expression always mean "return something"? If I write something like (params) => let i = 10, does it mean:
 (params) => {
    return let i = 10;
}
? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it always means that. Since `let` is a statement, not an expression, that won't work.

Comment: Basically, if you can't write `(blah)` you can't write `=> blah`

Comment: Thank you so much! So I can write (params) =>  i = 10 and (params) => { return i = 10; } right? and it will first assign 10 to i then return i which is 10?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It will be assigning to a variable declared in the outer scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! So let i has to be declared in an outer scope than this function right?

Comment: Of course. You can't put a declaration in the expression form of the arrow function.